# Screen sharing not working on Kali linux

Tags: display, kali-linux, windows-live-messenger, microsoft-teams, discord

****My issue****

1. When i try to share my screen via messenger or any other apps like ms teams my screen goes dark.*

Comment: Kali is not meant to be used as a general-purpose OS. The best course of action is to switch to something more universal, like Debian or Ubuntu. It will save you more headaches down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I too had the same problem. I have a dual-booting system having windows 8.1 and Kali Linux. I wanted to share a PPT with my friends and it failed. Of course, the same problem as you. A fine day, I was just checking around with desktop environments, like GNOME, KDE Plasma, SystemX (Or XSystem default) and I found out I could finally share my PPT with my friends. The thing is, GNOME for some reason does not support screen sharing. But after switching to SystemX Default, I was able to screen share.

Hope this helps.

EDIT: There are a few commands through which you can install a desktop environment, if you google out asking for SystemX Default Desktop Environment download for Kali Linux, you would get a few commands.

> sudo apt install -y kali-desktop-xfce

Comment: And when you login to your account, that is when you have the option to choose any desktop environment. You need to have them installed, when you first install Kali Linux.